# csrss.exe runs out of control

Tags: process, task-manager

It runs regularly at about 7,000k and maybe a flicker of 5% CPU, but every couple of days it goes nuts and shoots up to 200,000k of memory usage  and about 50% or more of CPU. A reboot fixes the issue until the next time. How do I avoid this all together?

Comment: Which version of Windows ?

Comment: @Hyppy: The security subsystem is **LSASS**. CSRSS, "client/server runtime", handles process creation, console windows, and (some) Win32 API.

Comment: Wow. You are completely right. It must have been too early for brain function when I wrote that. Deleted the comment to avoid confusing them :-)

Answer (score 0):

Run the SFC

[Windows XP, Vista 7 how to](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833)

.

> Use the System File Checker tool (SFC.exe) to determine which file is causing the issue, and then replace the file. To do this, follow these steps:
>   Open an elevated command prompt. To do this, click Start, click All Programs, click Accessories, right-click Command Prompt, and then click Run as administrator. If you are prompted for an administrator password or for a confirmation, type the password, or click Allow.
>   Type the following command, and then press ENTER:
>   sfc /scannow
>   The sfc /scannow command scans all protected system files and replaces incorrect versions with correct Microsoft versions.

.

If this does not solve it, you may be infected, see [this WIKI](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware)